# How to position an href element under a p element?

Tags: html

So I am trying to add some web links but I want them positioned underneath my `p` element. As of right now I currently have my `href` elements in line with my `p` element. So here is my current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
       <p>Here are a few links which may provide some insight to Lisa: 
         <a href="http://www.example.com" target="blank">Hold My Hand</a>
         <a href="http://www.example.com" target="blank">Lean on Me</a>
      </p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are they explicitly **inside** it if that isn't what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have your anchor tags wrapped inside a `p` tag. Either **place it outside the `p` tag** or **add a span to the text and make it 100% wide** (using bootstrap class) .

Wrap your `p` tag text with `span` tag

Since you are using bootstrap you can use the class `col-xs-12`

`<span class='col-xs-12'>Here are a few links which may provide some insight to Lisa: </span>`

Comment: The code example doesn't work in the general case. It depends on the bootstrap stylesheet (which the code the OP uses implies they are using, but isn't mentioned anywhere in the question or the tags). (I'm not sure it even works properly there, aren't `col-*` classes only supposed to appear in children of `class="row"` elements?) If that does work, then wrapping the links with that spen will wouldn't put them under the paragraph, just on a new line inside a bigger paragraph.

Comment: +Quentin .. `_(I'm not sure it even works properly there, aren't col-* classes only supposed to appear in children of class="row" elements?)_` it is the child of 'row' class.   It is not the direct child but it's a child so it works.

Comment: The terms you are looking for are "children" and "descendants". "Direct children" is a nonsense term.

Comment: `<span style='width:100%'>` generally won't do anything. By default `<span>` is `display: inline` so `width` does not apply.

Comment: +Quentin `If that does work, then wrapping the links with that spen will wouldn't put them under the paragraph, just on a new line inside a bigger paragraph.` yes that's true But I am sure that the OP is just looking for a UI where the links appear below the text and NOT the anchor tag being out of p tag in the mark-up. Hence my solution should be valid.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me .. with the span being inline and the terminology

Answer (score 0):

if you want to position your links under the text that you write you have many ways to do it...
you can use this tags `'<div>', '<br>', '<ul>'` like below

## Solution one (using div tag) :

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <p>Here are a few links which may provide some insight to Lisa: 
        <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoW3bqnr7tw"target="blank">Hold My Hand</a></div>
        <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A_j7aDTUCs"   target="blank">Lean on Me</a></div></p>
     </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

## Solution two (using ul and li tag) :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <p>Here are a few links which may provide some insight to Lisa: 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoW3bqnr7tw"target="blank">Hold My Hand</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A_j7aDTUCs"   target="blank">Lean on Me</a>
                </li>
            <ul>
        </p>
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

## Solution three (using br tag) :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <p>Here are a few links which may provide some insight to Lisa: 
            </br>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoW3bqnr7tw"target="blank">Hold My Hand</a>
            </br>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A_j7aDTUCs"   target="blank">Lean on Me</a>       
        </p>
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the closing tag, `</p>`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
       <p>Here are a few links which may provide some insight to Lisa: </p>
         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoW3bqnr7tw"target="blank">Hold My Hand</a>
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A_j7aDTUCs"   target="blank">Lean on Me</a>
        </div> 
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: There are still inside the paragraph. The paragraph is just taller.

Comment: That is because you don't close the paragraph until after the second link. You can move it if you don't want the links inside.

Comment: I am not the OP. I didn't do anything. The OP asked how to put them *under the paragraph*. Your answer told them how to put them on new lines **inside** the paragraph. After your edit, the *code* does what was asked but adds gratuitous line breaks and it has an explanation that talks about the line breaks but not about the position of the end tag.

Comment: I edited my answer, this should be what you are looking for

Comment: So now you suggest adding a `br` but don't have it in the suggested code.

Comment: I misread the question, but my edit removed the `<br>` tags and took the links from the `<p>` tag

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped, I did realize yesterday before my question was answered that I had my <p> inside which was causing the issue, but I will try a few of the other suggestions to see which way I like best....Thanks!